# Chrome shows a page with Errors but Firefox and Safari Show well

Tags: html, css, themes

I am using a Theme: http://bucketadmin.themebucket.net/

This theme have a timeline: http://bucketadmin.themebucket.net/timeline.html

If you open the page with firefox or Safari all work well, but until yesterday chrome shows with errors.

why happened? how i can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine on chrome for me. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'am using google Chorme for Mac, Here is a screen shot: http://prntscr.com/8c6ejx

Comment: Can't duplicate with Chromium under Linux.

Comment: So the line is just off by a bit? Should just need a change in position in your css. You might be using a percentage instead of an actual value, but without code we can't help you with much else.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting that page of yours shows that the line is `left:50%` changing it to `left:33%` looks about right, and if that messes with your design on other browsers you can use javascript to enable this change only for chrome.